# AngularJS setting default values for directive

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive, watch

In my parent controller:

```
//soemtimes view invoice has taxtotal defined
$scope.viewinvoice = {taxtotal:4}

//sometimes viewinvoice does not have taxtotal defined
$scope.viewinvoice = {}    

//sometimes it is defined but equal to 0
$scope.viewinvoice = {taxtotal:0}
```

In my parent view:

```
<div class="span6">
    <invoice invoice='viewinvoice'></invoice>
</div>
```

My directive:

```
.directive('invoice', [ function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      invoice:'='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="taxflag">
        <div> {{ calculate_grand_total() }} </div>
     </div>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  };
}]);
```

In my directive I want to set $scope.taxflag true based on the property:  $scope.invoice.taxtotal, the problem is if $scope.invoice.taxtotal is undefined I want to set the $scope.taxflag to false, and if the $scope.invoice.taxtotal is greater than 0 and is defined I want the $scope.taxflag set to true.

i.e.

```
if($scope.invoice.hasOwnProperty('taxtotal')){
    if($scope.invoice.taxtotal > 0 ) {
        $scope.taxflag = true;        
    } else {
        $scope.taxflag = false;
    }
} else {
    $scope.invoice.taxtotal = 0;
    $scope.taxflag = false;
}
```

I want this (above code) to act like 'initialization' code so whenever my 'viewinvoice' changes in the parent the $scope.taxflag and $scope.invoice.taxtotal will both be initially be set up correctly

I also want to trigger a change whenever the checkbox is checked:

i.e.

```
$scope.$watch('taxflag',function(newValue){
    if(newValue) {
        $scope.invoice.taxtotal = 5
    } else {
        $scope.invoice.taxtotal = 0;
    }
});
```

I am also using this $scope.invoice.taxtotal elsewhere in a function {{ calculate_grand_total() }} 
(in my directives view)

ie.

```
$scope.calculate_grand_total = function() {
    return $scope.invoice.taxtotal + 5;
}
```

but this is unable to render because $scope.invoice.taxtotal is not defined (at least initially) !!

Does this make sense? I have tried so many different combinations but I can't seem to get it working as I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this plunkr that tries to capture your question:

http://plnkr.co/edit/02QAC8m9xyF4pSyxnfOf

Basically, any code that depends on a value that can change should be in a watch. This means that your initialization code for setting taxflag belongs in a watch, so that it can update the tax flag if things change. This looks something like:

```
$scope.$watch('invoice.taxtotal', function(taxTotal) {
      if (!angular.isNumber(taxTotal)) {
        $scope.taxflag = false
        return;
      }
      if (taxTotal > 0) {
        $scope.taxflag = true;
      } else {
        $scope.taxflag = false;
      }
    });
```

Keep in mind watches are always executed the first time to initialize the values, so they essentially serve as both initialization code and update code.

As far as your `calculate_grand_total` function, if it is up to you to define what it should return if tax total or invoice are undefined. Simply check whether it is undefined and return the appropriate value, for example in my plunkr I return empty string:

```
$scope.calculate_grand_total = function() {
      if ($scope.invoice && angular.isNumber($scope.invoice.taxtotal)) {
        return $scope.invoice.taxtotal + 5;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure if my plunkr works exactly like you want it or not, but it should get you started in the right direction. Or serve as a starting point for further clarification.

Comment: Thanks this got me to what i wanted to do! One more thing should is it possible to set up a watcher on the $scope.taxflag so then i can update my $scope.invoice.taxtotal? or would i run into like a circular loop with the current watcher on the $scope.invoice.taxtotal

Comment: If you look at the code it actually does watch the taxflag. As long as  what both watches do is consistent, then there should be no loop. Watches only trigger if the value they produce is different from the last time they ran. For example when you set taxflag = true it triggers the watch which sets taxtotal = 5. This triggers the taxtotal watch which then sets taxflag to true again but this won't trigger taxfglag watch again because the value didn't change ( it is still true which is the same as the last time it ran)

Comment: Ooops, yeah I see it now didn't notice the plunker had a $watch on the taxflag. Thanks Alot !!

Answer (score 0):

related:
if you only want to set first-run defaults you can use [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) 
inside your link:

```js
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    // ....

    var settings_default = {
        setting1: true,
        setting2: {
            x: 0,
            y: 10
        },
    };

    //  order is important. last item overwrites previous
    scope.settings = angular.merge({}, settings_default, scope.settings);

    // ....
})
```